# What are different ways to delete item from web database

Tags: publishing

1) Delete the item from master and publish the item to web

2) Set unpublish date to an older date

3) check "Never Publish" checkbox and publish the item to web

4) disable the item and publish it

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: not sure about last 3 options,could you please let me know if last 3 options will also work

Comment: When you want to remove the item from the web database, do you still need it on the master database?

Comment: No i want it to be deleted from web db no matter about master

Answer (score 3):

Based on the different options you've shared and from the comments, the best approach is to use the Sitecore Publish Restrictions.

> Set unpublish date to an older date

It is an option but I won't recommend it as if the older date is met, then the item will be published. I know that it is still possible to add the date to a longer time, like year 2080.

> Check "Never Publish" checkbox and publish the item to web

Seems to be the best option out here because as long as the `never publish` checkbox is checked, the item will not be published to web and will get removed if it is already found on web.

> Disable the item and publish it

If by disabling the item, you mean using workflows, then it will work if the item stays in the draft mode but I won't recommend this option because workflow is set on version specific. You may have an item with 3 versions and only 1 version is in draft. The item will still be visible on web database.

**Note**

When you've update the item via the Publish Restrictions, you'll need to perform a publish so that the changes are reflected on the web database.